# How can I live Facebook Live preview streaming

Tags: facebook, live, live-streaming

We are developing an application where user can create a Live Event using API and can also go live.

As per per Facebook documentation when creating the event if we set "`published`" to false then user can view the stream in preview mode.

Well i am able to do live streaming and also able to watch live feed on my Facebook account, but when i am trying to to preview streaming i am not able to see the preview module any where in my Facebook account.

Even the **video** tag return by Facebook API shows the Live Feed correctly but not showing me the feed in preview mode.

Comment: Please accept the answer if that solves your issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can see the preview of Live Streaming even if you are doing everything using Facebook Live API.

I am assuming that you are creating live video using /#{some user or page id}/live_videos end point with POST method, and then using the returned RTMP URL to stream your video to that URL.

1. While creating object using above end point, send 'STATUS' field as
   'UNPUBLISHED'. Using this you tell Facebook that video hasn't gone
   LIVE yet.
2. Start the video streaming/encoding process using the
   returned RTMP URL.
3. Then use the returned object ID from step 1 to make next
   request to get stream preview link.
4. Send a get request at this end point /Object_ID with fields as
   'access_token' and 'dash_preview_url'.
5. Use the returned Dash Preview URL to preview the Live streaming using a
   [Dash Player](https://reference.dashif.org/dash.js/v2.6.3/samples/dash-if-reference-player/index.html)
6. After confirming that live preview quality is good enough to go Live, you  can send a post request with
   the object ID of video and 'STATUS' field with value 'LIVE_NOW' and
   your video becomes live for viewers.

You can also preview the video if you create video from Facebook site directly using Publishing Tools. Go to Video Library of Facebook Page, then create a Live Video, then copy the RTMP URL from there and then use your application/software to start streaming. In that Facebook pop-up window of Live, you can preview your video.

I have developed a  web-application [Shuriken Live](https://www.shurikenlive.com) for posting live videos to Facebook without using any 3rd party software and worked on this application for more than 6-7 months. You just need to upload the video or the link of the video that you wants to make live and leave the rest to the application.

In case you need any other clarification, you can ask me or refer to the official [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video/production-broadcasts#preview) for streaming preview.